# How do insert a html document in another html document

Tags: html, css

So I need to redirect people after clicking the button on my menu to the a specific corresponding page to that link, so I wrote this:

```
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

and I heard that I need to create another html document for each page, and so I did, but now I don't know how to insert it. (I am sorry if you can't see what I wrote in html but I can't seem to figure out how to write it and in the same time see it in html tags)

Comment: Welcome to SO Nicholas. Please don't add comments via "Answer" section. If you need to edit your question, just amend it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a link from and to those pages.

```
<a href='/home.html'>Go to home</a>
```

If you're trying to frame a page inside another, you'll need to use iframes.

```
<iframe src='/home.html'>Iframe can't be loaded</iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think he was just talking about the basic linking of html pages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a basic structure of:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='home.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
    <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

You need to create 3 html documents `home.html`, `about.html` and `contact.html`. You can place that navigation into each one of them along with other, unique content per page.

Answer (score 0):

You can run javascript like this when a button is pushed to open a new window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openWin() {
    window.open("http://www.mywebsite.com");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="openWin()">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```